# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined on Test with Hapijs and Lab in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, hapi.js, hapi.js-lab

Hi when i try to Test my API, written with Hapijs in Node, with Lab module i have this error:

> Preferences return 200 HTTP code wfor the make:

```
  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined

  at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
  at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)
```

the file index.js in the test directory is this:

```
'use strict';

var Lab = require('lab');

var Code = require('code');
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Joi = require('joi');

// internal object
var internals = {};

// Test shortcuts
var lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
var experiment = lab.experiment;
var describe = lab.describe;
var it = lab.it;
var before = lab.before;
var expect = Code.expect;

describe('Preferences', function() {

it("return 200 HTTP code wfor the make", function(done) {

  var server = new Hapi.Server();
  server.connection();
  server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/makes',
      config: {
          handler: require('../handlers/cars').getMakes,
          validate: {

          }
      }
  });

  server.inject({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/makes',

  }, function(res) {
      expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
      done();
  });
 });
 });
```

the file route.js is this:

```
module.exports = [{
path: '/makes',
method: 'GET',
config: {
//auth: 'session', only for testing disable the auth
auth: 'false',
handler: cars.getMakes
}
```

i have diseabled the authentication for this test and the handler is this:

```
getMakes: function (request, reply) {
Make
  .find()
  .sort('name')
  .exec( function(err, result) {

      if (err) {
         request.log(['server', 'database', 'error'], 'An error occured during the execution of the query');
     }

     return reply(result)
        .code(200);
    });
```

},
Can you explain me where is the error and why it show me this error type?

Comment: What is `Make.find()`?

Comment: @MattHarrison it's a query on a MongoDB database.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @ThinkingInBits not yet.

Comment: My problem was that I was getting my environment name from process.env.NODE_ENV and running a switch on that to set my mongodb connection url.  Make sure your mongodb is actually connecting.